# iOS Disable scroll for map view ONLY while zooming

Tags: ios, xcode, scroll, mkmapview, zooming

I am currently trying to look for a solution for disabling scrolling on a MKMapView while a person is zooming in/out.  Does anyone know of a solution to this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would check out this control which keeps the map centered on a point when zooming and it sounds like it should be able to achieve you desired effect. I'm not sure if you're using Objective-C or Swift since there is no tag, however you will be able to use this with either languages.

[SKMapsCenter](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/skmapscenter)

Comment: SKMapsCenter is nice, but it disables scrolling completely, not just when zooming.